# SSL_get_error() is returns value 5

Tags: openssl, client

I have been trying to create a SSL server and client applications. SSL_connect & SSL_accept fails. The SSL_get_error returns 5 and 2 respectively for SSL_connect & SSL_accept. What is the meaning of these return values?

Also, how would i found out what the issue is with the return value of SSL_get_error?

Thanks in advance.